# Hibernate loads Lazy entities eagerly with native query

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, lazy-loading

I was trying to optimise number of calls for my schema creational endpoint and get rid of n+1 problem. And I actually did it replacing them with only 2 calls. I have achieved it with Named Queries but I wonder if it is possible to do it with `nativeQuery=true`.
So, here is the situation:

Class A:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(AId.class)
@Table(name ="A")
@Data
class A implements Serializable{
 @Id
 @Column(name = "ID")
 private Integer id;

// code omitted...

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.Lazy)
@JoinColumns(
    ...
)
private B b;

}
```

Class B:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(AId.class)
@Table(name ="B")
@Data
class B implements Serializable{
 @Id
 @Column(name = "ID")
 private Integer id;

// code omitted...

@OneToMany(mappedBy="b", cascade=Cascade.ALL, fetch=FetchType.Lazy)
@JoinColumns(
    ...
)
private List<A> aList;

}
```

The problem occurs when I try to fetch the data with generated or native queries.
It grabs B entities when I fetch A though it's Lazy for A.

Expected behaviour is the executing a query as follows:

```
Hibernate:
    /* dynamic native SQL query */ SELECT
        *
    FROM
        A a
    WHERE
        a.ID IN (
            ?
        )
```

But right after this (no matter how I played with dynamic native query) I have one more query for B entity that I don't need:

```
Hibernate:
    /* load com.example.to.B */ select
        b0_.id as id1_1_0_,
    from
        B b0_
    where
        b0_.id=?
```

Why is this so and is there any way to avoid it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Set a breakpoint in e.g. `org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.EmptyStatementInspector#inspect` to see which code triggers the lazy initialization. Maybe it's your debugging that triggers this through a `toString` implementation.

Answer (score -1):

Hibernate cannot fetch lazily for `ToOne` relationships.

The field `b` can be null in `A`, and hibernate has to check with the table `b` before confirming to populate the field with null. The query for `B` you observed is the result.

You may consider using `@MapsId`, e.g.:

```
@ManyToOne
@MapsId(“id”) 
private B b;
```

You may read further about `@MapsId` here:
https://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/MapsId